# Controlling collapsed state in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there any way to control state of a collapsible portion of the page from javascript as per the example below?

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
<h3>Title</h3>
I'm some hidden content
</div>

<input type="button" value="click me to open the above section" onclick="....">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**outdated**

---

`ui-collapsible-content` inside your collapsible has an `aria-hidden` attribute - use this to check the state.

`$('yourthing a:first').click()`

toggles the state.

This is not very nice, but I haven't seen a nice implementation yet.

Answer (score 18):

I've found:

```
$('myCollapsible').trigger('collapse').trigger('updatelayout');
```

or

```
$('myCollapsible').trigger('expand').trigger('updatelayout');
```

to be the best way for controlling the collapsible elements

Comment: I'd suggest this be accepted as the answer - also, you can listen for the 'expand' and 'collapse' events like so:
`$('.ui-collapsible').on('expand', callback)`
`$('.ui-collapsible').on('collapse', callback)`